# Железо для .net

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу начать програмировать (.net) и обновить ПК под эти задачи. Подскажите что важнее: многопоточность или большая тактовая частота? Нужна ли хорошая видеокарта? По возможности посоветуйте самые популярные cpu/gpu

Comment: Нужен блокнот (достаточно встроенного в OS) и любой компьютер, который будет это все выполнять... А дальше уже зависит все от ваших потребностей и вашего проекта.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWIBgQRE_lA

Comment: Начитавшись ответов, дам совет: не гонитесь за железом под разработку вперед разработки. Начать при желании можно действительно и с блокнота на древнем ведре с болтами. Если будете сидеть и ждать, пока не появится топовая сборка, то, скорее всего, просто время впустую потратите, сама по себе скиллов она вам не добавит. Я в 2016 большую часть шарпового ООП вообще постигал на ноутбуке под Windows XP с 512 мб памяти и жестким диском на 30 гб. Не посоветую такой сетап на постоянной основе, но начинать разбираться с дотнетом можно на чем угодно.

Comment: _многопоточность или большая тактовая частота_ - странный вопрос, могоядерность быть может? вообще лушче 4 и более логических ядер, но хватит и двух. Тактовая частота без разницы. Можно вообще без компа начинать, есть всякие онлайн-компилаторы типа https://sharplab.io или https://dotnetfiddle.net, я с телефона на них периодически код пишу для проверки, потому что лень комп включать, чтобы ответ на StackOverflow написать.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт цкцпкцпук, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста какие вопросы тут задают  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic а также полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошая видеокарта не обязательна, достаточно будет и встроенной графики. А вот чем лучше процессор (и количество ядер, и быстродействие), тем веселее будет работать Visual Studio (и все остальные приложения). И главное ОЗУ побольше, 16+ ГБ. И хороший SSD [@CrazyElf], не менее 1000 Мб/с.

А начать можно на любом компе, с Notepad++ (или подобным редактором) и dotnet SDK.

i7-12800H 2.40 GHz, 32 ГБ ОЗУ и SSD PC801 NVMe SK hynix позволяют мне очень комфортно работать на виртуальных машинах.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151401/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor---net); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score -2):

VS Community тяжёлая, так что ОЗУ я бы поставил, по важности, на первое место.

Comment: Однако использовать VS совсем не обязательно

Comment: Но отказываться от её использования - это ещё нужно придумать, почему

Comment: @rotabor потому что есть VS Code, например?

Comment: @rotabor потому что слишком большое количество возможностей повышают порог вхождения, что важно при обучении.

Answer (score -3):

Нужен запредельно **стабильно** работающий компьютер, без наворотов. И без бустов. Все бусты по идее блокируются. Разгон как таковой влияет на тесты, и разгон мешает тестам. Нужна стабильная операционная система, а в общем смысле - вменяемо настроенная среда. Стабильная система - это семёрка. Потому что та же десятка совсем не стабильна, и это будет отражаться на тестах. При этом. Мощный комп не нужен, потому что на мощном компе будет работать всё. А на НЕ мощном компе оно будет работать? Смысл в железе получается в том, что железо почти не влияет на программирование как таковое, а вот на тесты - влияет. И ещё как влияет. И на самом деле тестовых компьютеров должно быть много, и старых и новых, и это должны быть ноутбуки для тестов и так далее. Про серверы я совсем молчу, там всё работает принципиально иначе, и тестить на серверах по идее вам тоже как то придётся. Итд итп.

Смысл прост. Если вы про программирование - то любой компьютер подходит. Но программирование без тестов - это нонсенс. Это прямо взаимосвязанные "вещщи". И вот для тестов нужны многие конфигурации железяк, операционных систем и рантаймов.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151400/discussion-on-answer-by-interceptortsk---net); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.